# Google OAUTH2 - Query User employee ID and user groups

Tags: oauth2-playground

I can send a GET to https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo, using an OAuth2 bearer token and get user information such as user name, email address, etc except for the following information:

1. Employee ID
2. Groups this user belongs to

Would be grateful if someone can help with what to do.